# Simple Flex Paint Application,how to save in the database not in image form

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, paint, save

I have a simple Flex paint application which let the user draw anything they want. My problem is how can I save it into MySQL database without  converting it to an image format. Moreover, I want it to be save and at the same time to retrieve in case there is an unfinished drawing.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Define what objects can be drawn, e.g. straight lines, points, polygons with controlled corners, etc. For each object, create serialization methods. It may be binary format (I guess you won't need search drawing in database by features used): object type first, then it's attributes. For line, it would be end points, color, maybe width and drawing style (solid, striped, dotted.)
Entire drawing will have some properties too, like width/height, format version. Write those in the header, then will go all drawing objects. If you need layers, you can make special tag for them, which will act like separator between drawing objects:
`header - layer 1 tag - line - line - line - layer 2 tag - square - circle`
Binary format also gives ability to save drawing into file (or in database as a blob.) Also, you can go with XML, it just will use much more bytes (but will be easier to debug.)